# I am trying to send data from Django DB to React

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

If client select a condition and search in React Front, the Django backend filters the DB that matches the condition and then sends it back to React. Succeeded in filtering the DB matching the conditions.

However, the data is a query set. How to send this to React?

Comment: For reference, the fetch function is used.

Comment: is the data is json array or just some counter variables?

Comment: I don't understand exactly, but it is a some kind of list of dictionary. To send it to React, I'm going to change it to Jason, but I'm not sure.